# Values from 2 tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to get values from one table and the count of the rows matching each of the values. More clearly,

- There is table A with columns `ID` and `TEXT`
- There is another table B with columns `ID`, `TEXT`, `A_ID` and `FRESH`

Some example data for table `A`:

```
+---+-------------+
|ID |    TEXT     |
+---+-------------+
| 1 | "Fruit"     |
| 2 | "Vegetable" |
+---+-------------+
```

And some data for table `B`:

```
+---+----------+----+-------+
|ID |   TEXT   |A_ID| FRESH |
+---+----------+----+-------+
| 1 | "Banana" | 1  |  Yes  |
| 2 | "Carrot" | 2  |  Yes  |
| 3 | "Apple"  | 1  |  No   |
+---+----------+----+-------+
```

As can be seen, `A_ID` contains a key for a row in table `A` that matches the specific `TEXT` value in each row of `B`.

So what I need is, I need to get the data like this:

```
1 | Fruit | 1
2 | Vegetable | 1
```

So in the above results, the first column is the `ID` of table `A`, and the second column is the `TEXT` of table `A` and the final (3rd) column is the **count of rows in table** `B` **in which the column** `FRESH` **has the value of "Yes"**.

I have been able to get the values similar to this, but with the total number of rows as the 3rd column, and not only the "Fresh" rows.

I tried this:

```
 SELECT A.ID, A.TEXT, count(B.FRESH) FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.A_ID;
```

and this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.TEXT, B.FRESH FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.A_ID;
```

But they don't get the expected result.

As I'm a kinda newbie to SQL, I'm stuck on this. So please help? I'm using SQLite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    A.TEXT, 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) 
             FROM B 
             WHERE B.A_ID=A.ID 
                 AND B.FRESH ='YES') AS FRESH
FROM A;
```

Comment: Just removing the `FRESH=` part solved it. Now works perfect... Thanks a lot :) Edit your answer and I'll select it as correct.

Comment: @Roshnal Oh sorry, Should use 'AS FRESH` to get Column name as 'FRESH' :)